# Как эмулировать запросы к Heroku через cURL PHP?

Tags: php, java, android, curl, heroku

Есть android-приложение, которое посылает запросы к серверу Heroku:

```
Parse.initialize(
    new Builder(this)
        .applicationId("aaa")
        .clientKey("bbb")
        .server("https://xxx.herokuapp.com/parse")
    .build()
);
```

Как передать те же параметры (applicationId и clientKey) в GET/POST-запросе, реализованном в cURL PHP?

Например, что-то вроде этого:

```
https://xxx.herokuapp.com/parse?application_id=aaa&client_key=bbb
```

Сам не знаком с архитектурой сервиса Heroku, пытаюсь разобраться какой в итоге HTTPS-запрос идет на сервер через Parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, данные для подключения передаются в заголовках:

```
$headers = array(
    "X-Parse-Application-Id: $MyApplicationId",
    "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: $Clientkey"
);

$handle = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```